# Javascript Cookie Script Opera Browser

Tags: javascript, cookies, opera

Trying to test the storage of cookies for a site I'm writing. Whenever I try reading a cookie to check for its existence, the console gives me nothing in return.

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
}
else var expires = "";
document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}

createCookie("name","value",7);

if (readCookie("name")){
    console.log("it works");
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can occur if your code is served from `file://` instead of `http://` protocol. 
Opera (and Chrome) doesn't save cookies if there is no domain and http communication.

Knowing the above, your options are:

1. Use IE (yuck) or Firefox
2. You can try running Opera with `--enable-file-cookies` flag (This works on Chrome for me, but not sure about Opera)
3. Serve your file over http server. If you're on MAC, it's as simple as:

   $ cd /project_folder/

   $ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000

where `/project_folder/` contains your html file(s).
You can then use any browser to access http://localhost:8000/your_html_file.html

Source: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=535